# Get a value from clicking on a masterpage hyperlink to child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, hyperlink, master-pages

I am trying to create a website that will allow sharing photos (as a basic project),
and i encountered a problem. 
On my masterPage there are links with category names and I need that when i click on one of them I would get a Value into a variable in a child page (in the css code page).
I am pretty new to masterpages and have no idea how to do so, i tried in some ways but just couldn't. 
As an example:

A string variable in the css section of the child page "Gallery.aspx" that would get the value of the category name when it's clicked in the masterpage.

Comment: im not sure i understand your problem. do you want to update a CSS code in a web page by triggering an anchor element in the masterpage? maybe it would be easier if you tell us what are you trying to accomplish maybe we could provide a better solution.

Comment: I have a gallery page that shows all of the pictures in my database. In my master page there are hyperlinks named by category names. I want to create a situation that when a hyperlink in the master page is clicked, his name would be transferred into a string variable in my gallery.css page.

Comment: gallery.css? that is not a webpage right.. its a stylesheet, im not sure how you can achieve that... im assuming you are having the categories in you master page and want to display the images in a child page based on the category selected?

Comment: Exactly! and woops, gallery.cs ><

Answer (score 0):

```
Hyperlink hh=(Hyperlink)Master.FindControl("control_name");
```

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.